# Ruby on Rails Project using association models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm kinda new in Ruby on Rails  and I created a two models: user and group. For every user there is only one group from the two either male or female, and I can't connect them together

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user
end
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to read it out loud.  So a `User` belongs to a `Group` and a `Group` has many `User`?  No - a `Group` has many `Users` so you have just one small typo to fix.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

Now you can do `User.first.group` which will give you the first user's group or you can do it in the opposite direction, `Group.first.users` which will give you all the users associated with the first group.

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveRecord, the standard convention is that has_many associations are plural and has_one associations are singular. For your example

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class ExclusiveGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
```

Saying has many user doesn't make sense. On the other hand saying has one user also doesn't make sense. That's why the convention are plural for has_many and singular for has_one

Hope this helps.